# By this “smoothness means fast decay” principle

Tags: sentence-construction

This is the starting part of a sentence in my paper.

Here 'smoothness means fast decay' is a whole sentence. Is it appropriate to use it in this way? Is it too long here?

Comment: The sentence **Smoothness means fast decay....** is grammatical. Whether it is meaningful or appropriate is impossible to judge from the little information that you provide.

Comment: Is it a common practice in writing?

Comment: Is **what** a common practice?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Is "**Smoothness means fast decay**" the first sentence in your paper? Or is "**Here 'smoothness means fast decay' is a whole sentence.**" the first sentence in your paper?

Comment: My sentence starts with the title. My paper does not start with this sentence.

Comment: You can't start a sentence with a title, really. And that sentence cannot be a proper title. It is, of course, a full sentence as it has a subject, a verb and a predicate.

Comment: You say it's "the starting part of a sentence," but you then say it is "a whole sentence." Which is it? What is the actual, complete sentence?

Comment: @Bassford  My concern is whether using a whole sentence as an adjective is okay.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to address users' concerns. Please make sure to provide all the context. See [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) and the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for tips and examples.

Answer (score 1):

## The sentence is correct

I come from a mathematical background and I think you're probably talking about Fourier transforms. If it is obvious through your title or through the following sentences, then this sentence alone is adequate, however, it could be confusing if you don't state it outright in the sentence. In that case, it might be better to start with **"In Fourier transforms, smoothness means fast decay."**

Comment: The grammaticality is not the issue. The issue is: Can it be a title? I doubt it. It's a principle.

Comment: The question was not about whether something can be the title of a paper. The  "title" mentioned in the comment seems to be *this question's title*,  which is a quote from the OP's paper.

Comment: @laugh You got it.